# Having issues with gulp watch glob should be String or Array, not object

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I keep getting the following error with my gulpfile for the watch plugin

```
‘watch* errored after XXms
Error in plugin ‘gulp-watch’
Message:
glob should be String or Array, not object
```

Here is what my code in the gulpfile looking like

```
function sassWatch(sassData) {
    gulp.src(sassData.watch)
    .pipe(watch({glob:sassData.watch, emitOnGlob: true}, function() {
        gulp.src(sassData.sass)
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions))
        .on('error', function(err) {
                gutil.log(err.message);
                gutil.beep();
                global.errorMessage = err.message + " ";
        })
        .pipe(checkErrors())
        .pipe(rename(sassData.name))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(sassData.output))
        .pipe(livereload());
    }));
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the pre-1.0.0 way of providing a globbing pattern to gulp-watch, but your gulp-watch plugin has a version >= 1.0.0.

The 1.0.0 release of gulp-watch changed the method signature from:

```
watch([options, callback])
```

to

```
watch(glob, [options, callback])
```

This means you have to provide your globbing pattern like this:

```
.pipe(watch(sassData.watch, { /*other options*/ }, function() {
```

Note that the `emitOnGlob` option was removed in 1.0.0. Read [this github issue](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/82) and the [Migration to 1.0.0 notes](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/d97d94bd60df9c4656129b4261f4ba77d33bf2d5/README.md#migration-to-100) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand how to use the new `watch`, could you provide a more full explanation? I've been hunting for information online without success in the past hour. Thanks